# Does the linux kernel perform load-balancing or task migration for real-time tasks?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, real-time, load-balancing

It's clear where load-balancing and task migration takes place in the CFS code in fair.c, but I've looked through the rt.c code and am still not sure whether there is inter-core load balancing happening with the real-time tasks as well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you find out the answer?. you are talking about linux with RT patch right?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Here's an article about KernelShark which can help you see it happening too: http://lwn.net/Articles/425583/